# Powershell script to find services running on remote servers

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0

Need a Powershell script to list out the services running on remote servers.

Is there any way to list out the name of services running on remote servers without logging in individually on remote servers and checking?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The short answer is: with PowerShell remoting set up on all target servers, use something like `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $arrayOfServers { Get-Service }`

Comment: You don't have to use Invoke-Command because Get-Services already provides the option for an remote host.

Comment: @Patrick: This method of remoting is obsolescent - don't rely on cmdlet-individual `-ComputerName` parameters, especially since the upcoming PowerShell v7 - meant to be supersede Windows PowerShell - won't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the the following command and specify the remotesystem you would like to get the services from. The parameter ComputerName is a strin array. So you could pass more then one system to the command.

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $ComputerName
Get-Service -ComputerName ($ComputerName1, $ComputerName2)
```

Comment: Using cmdlet-individual `-ComputerName` parameter for remoting is obsolescent and shouldn't be recommended anymore, especially since the upcoming PowerShell v7 - meant to be supersede Windows PowerShell - won't support it.
Cmdlets with individual `-ComputerName` parameters use an older, less firewall-friendly form of remoting unrelated to [_PowerShell_ remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-5.1) that the - obsolete since v3 - WMI cmdlets also use (the latter were replaced by the CIM cmdlets).

Comment: It is therefore better to consistently use the firewall-friendly PowerShell remoting with its generic remoting commands (`Invoke-Command`, `Enter-PSSession`, ...).

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable answers. I am getting following error message:  PS C:\Users\myuser> Get-Service -ComputerName xx.yy.168.194
Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'xx.yy.168.194'. This operation might require other privileges.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Service -ComputerName xx.yy.168.194
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand @peterSmith

Comment: the user you are running the command will need permission at the remote host. Try the command as an user with local administration rights at the remote system. Or use `Invoke-Command` with the `-Credential` parameter to give the needed credentials directly.